# How to put ads in apps for Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, app-store, ads, mac-app-store

As AdMob or iAd is not yet available on Mac, how can we add ads to Mac Apps? Is Adsense allowed? Or is there any other available ad platform? Thanks.

Comment: This is an old question but does anybody have any new ad networks to add to the list?

Comment: Adsense is not allowed. It is prohibited by Adsense rules to place their ads inside of the desktop applications. It's better not to try, the can block the account.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

BuySellAds.com has a [Cocoa framework](http://developer.buysellads.com/) for embedding ads in Mac applications.  AppBodega appears to be among the first applications to use this for in-application ads.  Mac.Appstorm.net has a [bit of additional information on this](http://mac.appstorm.net/general/app-news/buysellads-to-integrate-ads-into-desktop-mac-apps/).

Other Mac applications use ads from [The Deck](http://decknetwork.net/) (invitation only) or [Fusion Ads](http://fusionads.net/) (again, fairly exclusive).

While there is no guarantee that anything will or will not be accepted for the Mac App Store, there are no explicit restrictions regarding advertising in the current published guidelines.  You do need to obtain consent before transmitting any user-specific information, but that may only impact any analytics data you gather.

Comment: I know this is a very old answer and none of the links works any more. Could Mr. Larson or any others provide some insight into the current state of this area?

Answer (score 4):

That is true. AdMob,iAd and Adsence are Not available on Mac Store. If you want to put ads in Mac apps, you firstly should find an ad platform supports Mac applications.

Actually, I used to work as a Windows app publisher. We also had similar confusion with you.I tried to Google keywords such as mac ad platform, mac ad sdk, it only showed few ad platform or ad agency can support mac applications. I found some but never ran ads on them: buysellads.com, adduplex.com, mobfox.com and desktopad.com. You may check one by one if you have enough time.You had better contrast them, such as ad fill rate, ad format, price,etc. Then select most efficient one.

Anyway, it is not easy to find an extremely suitable mac app platform for your apps. Sometimes, there are limits on Mac Store. You just need to keep patience to Google more keywords related to mac ad platform.